# UnityでAnimationClipの一部のポーズに固定して利用する方法

Tags: unity3d

Unityで，Tポーズで作られているモデルデータと，そのボーンのデータ，およびアニメーションデータがあります．このとき，そのアニメーションデータの指定のフレームの姿勢を取るように固定させる方法はありますか？できれば，エディタ上の表示とも一致させたいです．
具体的な利用方法として，アクションゲームの主人公のアクション途中のポーズをタイトル画面で固定して表示させたいです．

Answer (score 0):

Animationのspeedを0に設定、指定フレームへtimeを移動
すればいいのではないでしょうか